# could not load object from location , error subreport jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a main report and sub report, when I run it in my computer it works fine. But when I've jar the application and run it in another computer, it didn't work and show error **"Could not load object from location"**. I've placed the main report and the sub report in same folder, but it won't work. The error tells that the sub report always read the old directory.
Here is my code :

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JasperManager.loadXmlDesign(new File(".").getCanonicalPath()+ "\\report\\report2.jrxml");
```

report2 is my main report.

And here is my subreport expression :

```
$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subreport1.jasper"
```

Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest instead of specifying the `jrxml` path as the **Subreport Expression** , you can just compile the subreport from the classpath at runtime, then pass the compiled subreport to the report as a parameter. Then use that parameter as the **Subreport Expression**

**Java Code**

```
JasperReport jasperReport = null;
String reportName = "MySubreport.jrxml";

//load the the subreport jrxml from the classpath
InputStream ins =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(reportName);
JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(ins);

try {
    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
} catch (JRException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//pass the jasperReport object as a parameter to the report
Map<String, Object> reportParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
reportParams.put("SUB_JASPER", jasperReport);

//finally pass the parameter map to the report.
```

**Jrxml**

1. Create a report parameter with **Parameter Class** set to `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport`
2. Click on the subreport, set the **Expression Class** property to `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport` and **Subreport Expression** to the parameter you created that contains the compiled subreport.

This way, you just need to put your jrxmls in your classpath then your good to go.

Comment: -Thanks for answering so fast :) . I've found the solution, that i must write the path like this $P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "\\report\\subreport1.jasper" . Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: Good to hear you solved your own problem. But in the future, for you to be less problematic with the path of your report, you might want to follow my suggestion.

Comment: i'll try your suggestion, of course, i really appreciate that :)